# What can we say about the joint distribution of $\left(X,g(X)\right)$, where $g$ is an injective function?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, independence, multivariate-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable. What can we say about the joint distribution of 
$$\left(X,g(X)\right),$$ where $g$ is an injective function?

Comment: If the inverse $g^{-1}$ of $g$ exists then this would be easy:
$$P(X\leq x, g(X)\leq y) = P(X\leq x, X \leq g^{-1}(y)) = P(X\leq \min\{x,g^{-1}(y)\}).$$
However, $g$ being injective is only a necessary condition for the existence of the inverse. hence no answer, but a comment.

Comment: @chRrr What if we restrict the image set of $g$ to the elements with an inverse image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on chRrr 's comment:

Let us assume that $X$ is continuous and $g$ is increasing.

Let us say that $g$ is of the form $g:S \rightarrow T$. Let us define
$$
V=\{y\in T  ~|~  \exists x \in S ~ g(x)=y\}
$$

Now we define 
$$
\begin{align}
f:S & \rightarrow V \\
x & \mapsto g(x)
\end{align}
$$

$f$ is bijective, so we can consider the function $f^{-1}$. This means that
$$
P(X\leq x, g(x)\leq y) = P(X\leq x, f(x)\leq y) = P(X\leq x, X\leq f^{-1}(y))
$$

$$
= P(X\leq \min \{x, f^{-1}(y)\})
$$

If $g$ is decreasing
$$
P(X\leq x, g(x)\leq y) = P(X\leq x, X\geq f^{-1}(y)) = P(f^{-1}(y)\leq X\leq x)
$$

If $X$ is discrete
$$
P(X= x, g(x)= y) = P(X=x) \mathbb I(x=f^{-1}(y))
$$